# difference between Impleo (+acc) and Impleo (+abl)

Tags: verbs, case

I found two instances in Augustine's *Confessions*:

> "... caelum et terram ego impleo" (book 1, cap. 2)

and:

> "et quo refundis quidquid impleto caelo et terra restat ex te?" (book 1, cap. 3)

I tried to look up [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=impleo), which contains examples for both instances, but I can't really see a difference between them. On what occasions should we prefer one for the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common usage of *impleo* is with the accusative and ablative.

- The **accusative** tells you **what** is being filled.
- The **ablative** tells you **with what** it is being filled.

  - N.B. By analogy with plenus + gen. (= "full of X"), sometimes the **genitive** is used here instead.

For example:

> **Impleo poculum (acc.) vino (abl.)** = "I fill the cup with wine."

Augustine provides a handy usage of this in *Confessions* I.3:

> **...te toto imples omnia** = "You fill all things with your whole self."

Your example quote uses the ablative, but in an entirely different way. *Impleto caelo et terra* is an **ablative absolute** with the past participle of *impleo*, and is syntactically separate from the rest of the sentence. Here's how you should parse it:

```
et quo refundis                    And where do you pour back
    quidquid                           whatever 
        impleto caelo et terra             once heaven and earth have been filled
    restat ex te?                      remains of you?
```

Or, more fluidly:

> And, once heaven and earth have been filled, where do you pour back what remains of you?

Comment: really better answer than I could imagine. thanks for explaining all this!

Comment: we may say (I'm practicing what I've just learnt) : Augustinus, scriptus ibro, capitulum tertium exemplis vocabuli 'impleo' implevit .( I want to say: Augustine, when the book was written, filled chapter three with examples of the word 'impleo')

Comment: Yes, that works, except you'd want to say "scripto libro"!

Comment: yes you right, I meant to write it :) but because my latin is too weak I wasn't sure about the ppp of "scibo", so when I found it was scriptus I forgot to use scripto. :)

Comment: A minor point on the translation of your last example: according to the (correct) parsing of the complex sentence and given the syntactic relevance of word order, I understand that the Ablative Absolute should not have "scope" over the main sentence (_refundis_) but **only** over the subordinate one (_restat_). Accordingly, i.e., syntactically speaking, the Ablative Absolute, as an adverbial clause, should only modify the latter.